# Azure logic app join action after file iteration

Tags: arrays, json, azure, parsing, azure-logic-apps

I have a quite simple workflow.

[image]

[image]
I have a text file including rows.

MLC_AFNV0006F0F5.0F.F5#0F:05:FF055F3F0F39                                                                                          RBUAKFRN    0000000F900000000F05527
MLC_AFWF0006F0F5.0F.F5#0F:FF:F9055F7F0090                                                                                          RBUAKFRN    0000000F900000000F05527
MLC_AFWF0006F0F5.0F.F5#0F:F6:0F035F7F0356                                                                                          RBUAKFRN    0000000F900000000F03525
MLC_AFWF0006F0F5.0F.F5#0F:F6:0F035F7F0356                                                                                          RBUAKFRN    0000000F900000000F03527
MLC_DIRT000FF0F5.0F.F5#0F:F6:0F00005683598F                                                                                        DIAPKFY     00000000570000000FDOD9N

I get the file content (rows above) with the logic app and filter out all rows where "525" exists in certain position of the row (163, 3). This seems to work so that the for each action replaces the "525" rows with "":
``
if(equals(substring(item(), 163, 3), '525'), '', item())

``

First row ok
[image]

Third row this should be filtered out and it seems that it is empty:
[image]

However the Joining iterated rows is the thing which I havent get working. How to join these rows which are ok (525 is not existing in substring(item(), 163, 3))? I have tried everything but havent got it working. What is going wrong here?

My join action: `if(empty(outputs('Row_iteration')), '', join(outputs('Row_iteration'), ' '))`

When running the workflow it goes ok until the for each action starts.

First row ok
[image]

Third row this should be filtered out and it seems that it is empty:
[image]

However the Joining iterated rows is the thing which I havent get working. How to join only these rows which are ok (525 is not existing in substring(item(), 163, 3))? I have tried everything but havent got it working. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, and you need to modify certain values in certain rows of this array, you don't need to iterate through all the rows. The simplest and quickest solution will be using the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#select-action) action, which does just what you need: it creates a new array from the values in an existing array.